# How to remove unity heap memory from browser?

Tags: javascript, unity-webgl

I try to load WebGL game in browser with in facebook app. When I load the game it allocates 512 mb unity heap in browser heap. I can close the game and move on to another screen of my app with out refreshing the page. But the allocated unity heap memory doesn't clear until I refresh the page. This increases the browser memory and crash the browser very often.

So is there any way to clear the unity heap from javascript when I unload the WebGL game?

Comment: if you solve the problem then please share the solution

Answer (score 0):

WebGL in Unity is fairly new so there are bugs or configuration setups to be expected. Nevertheless have a look at these blog posts by Unity Engineers. You will have to profile your application/game before you decide how much WebGL memory you need on the heap prior to building it.

- https://blogs.unity3d.com/2016/09/20/understanding-memory-in-unity-webgl/
- https://blogs.unity3d.com/2016/12/05/unity-webgl-memory-the-unity-heap/

Furthermore some 32-bit browsers might have memory limitations so try it with 64-bit browsers or decrease the amount of memory taken by textures and sound after looking at your profiler information in Unity.

Comment: Allocating required memory based on application need is fine. But I want to know how to release that memory when I unload the application from browser